# when I ran the program, the output was two calls to dumpregs

Tags: assembly, x86

[image]

Calculates the correct change in quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
prompti db "Enter the amount",0
invaildamount db "The amount is invalid amount",0
change db 0
quarters db 0
nickels db 0
dimes db 0
pennies db 0
num db 0
Qcount db "The number of quarters is",0
Dcount db "The number of dimes is",0
Ncount db "The number of nickels is",0
Pcount db "The number of pennies is",0
.code
main proc
xor ax, ax
L1:
mov edx, offset prompti
call writestring
call crlf
call readint
cmp al, 0
je alldon
cmp al, 100
jge invalidamount
   sub al, 100
mov change, al
call dumpregs
xor ax, ax
mov al, change
mov bl, 25
div bl
add al , quarters
mov quarters, al
call dumpregs
mov num, ah
xor ah, ah
mov al, num
mov bl, 10
div bl
add al, dimes
mov dimes, al
   mov num, ah
xor ah, ah
mov bl, 5
   div bl
add al, nickels
mov nickels, al
mov num, ah
    xor ah, ah
mov bl, pennies
div bl
add al, pennies
mov pennies, al
jmp alldon



invalidamount:
   mov edx, offset invalidamount
   call writestring
call crlf
jmp L1
alldon:
mov edx, offset Qcount
call writestring
call crlf
mov al, quarters
call writeint
call crlf
mov edx, offset Dcount
call writestring
call crlf
mov al, dimes
call writeint
call crlf
mov edx, offset Ncount
call writestring
call crlf
mov al, nickels
call writeint
call crlf
mov edx, offset Pcount
call writestring
call crlf
mov al, pennies
call writeint
call crlf
exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Because you call dumpregs twice?

Comment: Yes I am not sure. I might have call dumpregs twice, Can you help me find a solution?